# Update interests values in postgresql by days

Tags: java, postgresql, firebird

I need some help here, at least a hint, in how to write this query that works in Firebird to PostgreSQL. It's about interests auto-update per day. Always worked that way, but now we are migrating and I can't find the solution although I tried many different ways.

```
execute block as 
declare variable id Integer;
begin 
for select BILL_ID from BILLS into :id do update BILLS set BILL_INTEREST_VALUE = 
TRUNC(replace(((((BILL_VALUE * BILL_PERCENT) / 100) / 30) * datediff(day, BILL_INTEREST_DATE, current_date)),',','.'), 2)where BILL_ID = :id and BILL_CLIENT_ID="+id+"
and datediff(day, BILL_INTEREST_DATE, current_date) >=  BILL_DAYS_INTEREST and 
BILL_VALUE > 0.00;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why that used a procedural language, as far as I can tell, this can be replaced with a single UPDATE statement without a loop:

```
UPDATE BILLS 
  SET bill_interest_value = trunc( (((BILL_VALUE * BILL_PERCENT) / 100) / 30) * (current_date - bill_interest_date))
WHERE bill_id IN (SELECT bill_id FROM bills) --<< essentially useless
  AND bill_client_id = ?
  AND current_date - bill_interest_date >=  bill_days_interest 
  AND bill_value > 0.00;
```

The above assumes that `bill_interest_date` is a `date` column (not a timestamp)

Comment: Well, I'm retyping an old code. So that was the way they release to keep the amounts auto-updated. I'm gonna try your exemple. Thanks. Yes its stored as Date. Hope that works!!!

Comment: The condition `bill_id IN (SELECT bill_id FROM bills)` can even be removed entirely, either way you're going to update all rows in `BILL`. In any case, the original code looks like code that was written to circumvent the 'unstable cursor' problem that can affect updates in Firebird 2.5 and earlier.

Comment: Thank you Mark, you helped me a lot, works perfectly! thats exactly the firebird 2.5 and earlier versions problem and I'm dealing with it for a couple days.

Comment: @DennisHaubertPonssoni It was a_horse_with_no_name that answered your question, not me.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel how would that code evade 'unstable cursor' (does `for select * ... do insert` ever ends normally ?) and why even should it (if update can update newly inserted rows - then let it just do!)? To me it seems like verbatim retelling a pre-SQL ISAM code, like Delphi code working with DBF/Paradox tables.